# Need reference on indicies of critical points

Tags: differential-geometry

I came across the term "index-1 critical point" in my reading, and I would like to know if there are some good references to learn about indices of critical points of smooth functions.

The wikipedia page just defines what they are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics), but I like to know more about them.

Unfortunately, I have no background in differential geometry at all,so any reference that does not require substantial background in differential geometery would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: When your smooth function $f$ has a critical point $p$, look at the Hessian of $f$ at $p$ (which is nonsingular in the case that $p$ is a critical point). The index of the critical point $p$ is the dimension of the maximal subspace of the tangent space on which $\text{Hess}_p f$ is negative definite. See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_bilinear_form) for more detail on the last bit.

Comment: How do you know that the Hessian of f at $p$ is nonsingular when $p$ is a critical point?

Comment: Oops, I don't I lied. Thanks for pointing that out. Such points are called nondegenerate critical points. In any case, the above still holds, minus the bit where I said the Hessian is nonsingular.

Comment: @MikeMiller: "I back you", in that if an author speaks of the index of a critical point, they're probably speaking of Morse functions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending what you want to know, there's not much to say. Let's assume $p$ is a *non-degenerate* critical point (i.e., the Hessian $H(p)$ is non-singular) of a function $f$ having continuous second partial derivatives. By equality of mixed partial derivatives, the Hessian is a symmetric matrix, and therefore admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. The *index* of the critical point $p$ is the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces with negative eigenvalue. Loosely this is "the number of directions you can approach $p$ from below" (i.e., through values of $f$ smaller than $f(p)$).

The classic example is a [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) resting on edge on a flat table top, with $f$ the height about the table. There are four critical points: the very bottom (a local minimum, so of index $0$); the bottom and top of the hole (each of index $1$; there's a unique eigendirection through which you can "ascend" into each critical point); and the very top (an absolute maximum for height, and therefore of index $2$ since the torus is $2$-dimensional).

If you need more than the linked Wikipedia page on Morse theory, the Standard Reference is probably Milnor's *Morse Theory*.

Comment: When you say "the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces with negative eigenvalue", do you mean the dimension of the space spanned by $\bf all$ the eigenvectors whose eigenvalues are negative?

Comment: Yes,@user12345678910. These are equivalent.